# Complex SQL Query of Group BY

Tags: sql

I have 4 Tables  ( Cattle , Farm , Vaccine , vReminder ) 
I want to select from Vaccine Reminder table all reminders to be shown as

( 2 ( Cows ) have ( Vaccine Name 1) from ( Farm Name 1) on this Date )
( 3 ( Horses) have ( Vaccine Name 1) from ( Farm Name 1) on this Date ) 
( 1 ( Cow) have ( Vaccine Name 5) from ( Farm Name 2) on this Date ) and so On

I wrote this Query But it is not Grouping the same Vaccine Type that are located for the same Farm if the cattle is of the same type : 
[image]

My Query :

```
  SELECT 
  (Select v.vName from vaccine as v where v.vID= vr.[vID]),
  vr.[Type],
  vsD,
  COUNT(vr.[Type]),
  f.farmName
  FROM [QNFARM].[dbo].[vReminder] as vr  inner join
       [cattle] as c on c.RFID = vr.RFID inner join
       farm as f on f.farmID = c.fID    
  Group by
  vr.vID,
  vr.Type,
  vsD,
  vr.RFID,
  f.farmName
```

But as you See in the screen shot that it is Vname Pinkeye for to same breeds and same Dates and same Farm it does not Group Them .

Comment: Can you remove the vr.vID from the groupBy and try again ?

Comment: Also in your select clause you have only vName , and your aggregate functions are inside the where clause.

Comment: if i remove the vid it will give an error ( vid must be list either in aggregate function or the group)

Comment: You know that there is a priority of the operations in group by. The first in the list comes first the second comes second and so on... So what is your group by priority what do you want to come first.

Comment: I got that.  must be under each farm will count based on the breed  than based on vid of same date

Comment: I Found the Problem , I was also grouping by the RFID which is the ID of the cattle and that is preventing out the grouping function to collect the same vID

Answer (score 0):

The Problem that I was grouping also by RFID of the cattle that was preventing the group function to collect the Same vaccine id , so the correct query is :

```
  SELECT f.farmName,vr.[Type],
  (Select v.vName from vaccine as v where v.vID= vr.[vID]) as vName,vr.vsD
  ,COUNT(*) as Num
  FROM [QNFARM].[dbo].[vReminder] as vr inner join  [cattle] as c on c.RFID=vr.RFID  inner join farm as f on f.farmID=c.fID    Group by f.farmName,vr.Type,vr.vID,vr.vsD
```

I just remove the RFID from the group by statement and the result now 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a subquery to get the vaccine name.  Just use joins:

```
SELECT v.vName, vr.[Type], vsD, COUNT(*), f.farmName
FROM [QNFARM].[dbo].[vReminder] vr INNER JOIN
     [cattle] c 
     ON c.RFID = vr.RFID  INNER JOIN 
     farm f 
     ON f.farmID = c.fID INNER JOIN
     vaccine v
     ON v.vid = vr.vid
GROUP BY v.vname, vr.Type, vsD, f.farmName;
```